# Why Wordpress AJAX returns undefined however it works fine when I add static url instead of dynamic function?

Tags: theme-development, ajax, rest-api

**Code from functions.php**

```
function university_files()
{
   wp_localize_script('main-university-js', 'universityData', array(
        'root-url' => get_site_url()
    ));
};

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'university_files');
```

**Code from JS**

```
getResults() {
    $.getJSON(
      universityData.root_url +
        "/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?search=" +
        this.searchField.val(),
      (posts) => {
        this.resultsDiv.html(`
        <h2 class ="search-overlay__section-title">General Information</h2>
          ${
            posts.length
              ? `<ul class="link-list min-list">`
              : `No General Information Marched your search`
          }
            ${posts
              .map(
                (item) =>
                  `<li><a href="${item.link}">${item.title.rendered}</a></li>`
              )
              .join("")}
          ${posts.length ? `</ul>` : ""}
        
        `);
        this.isSpinnerVisible = false;
      }
    );
  }
```

[image: Image from inspect element where the error can be seen]

Comment: you shouldn't build your HTML out of strings in javascript, it's insecure. jQuery already provides methods of doing it by building nodes. Don't do this: `jQuery( '<a href="' + url '">test</a>')` it's dangerous, you should do `jQuery( 'a', { href: url, text: 'test' } )` instead it's safer and avoids a lot of exploits and attacks

Comment: This is new. I just started using jquery. Before I was relaying on plain js

Comment: it's the same problem if you try and do it with plain JS by joining together HTML strings, build your DOM nodes and append them rather than passing it a big HTML string and it'll be much harder to hack you. The browser will do a tonne of security stuff for you, like checking the URL is a valid URL and formatting everything properly for free

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have:

```js
universityData.root_url
```

But you localised:

```php
'root-url' => get_site_url()
```

`root_url` != `root-url`

Comment: Thanks Tom. I really hate that after 3 years in wordpress and coding, I am still making syntax mistakes

Comment: happens to the best of us :) I once spent 2 days stuggling because I'd use `{}` instead of `[]` on a `useState` call